# Multiple Gradle duplicate classes after excluding module from the dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Gradle file includes the following dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'

    implementation 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12'
    implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0-2'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml:aalto-xml:1.0.0'

    implementation group: 'xerces', name: 'xercesImpl', version: '2.8.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:0.3.0'
    implementation('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'commons-codec'
    }
    implementation('com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev83-1.23.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.23.0'
}
```

Amongst several other multiple class errors, `commons-codec` has the following usage in the dependency tree

```
+--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0
|    +--- com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0
|    |    +--- com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.23.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.23.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
|    |    |    |    \--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1
|    |    |    |         +--- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.0.1
|    |    |    |         +--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
|    |    |    |         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3
\--- commons-codec:commons-codec:{strictly 1.3} -> 1.3 (c)
```

Figure the problem might be related to a transitive dependency but as far as I can understand through the analysis of the dependency tree, only `org.apache.httpcomponents` is using it as a library and yet, for some reason I can't grasp, the exclude declaration in the Gradle build file is not working as intended.

Gradle build log related to the `commons-codec` module

```
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.BinaryDecoder found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.BinaryEncoder found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.Decoder found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.Encoder found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.EncoderException found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.StringDecoder found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.StringEncoder found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.StringEncoderComparator found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.BinaryCodec found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.language.DoubleMetaphone found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.language.DoubleMetaphone$DoubleMetaphoneResult found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.language.Metaphone found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.language.RefinedSoundex found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.language.Soundex found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.language.SoundexUtils found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.net.BCodec found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.net.QCodec found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.net.QuotedPrintableCodec found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.net.RFC1522Codec found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
  Duplicate class org.apache.commons.codec.net.URLCodec found in modules commons-codec-1.3.jar (commons-codec:commons-codec:1.3) and docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar (docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar)
```

Note that `docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar` is a jar added to the libs folder. Not sure why those jar files are not being displayed in the dependency tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, by excluding all instances of the transitive dependency, it worked

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'commons-codec', module: 'commons-codec'
}
```

Are there any downsides to this approach? By doing this, aren't all methods included in the `google-api-client-android` module that use `commons-codec` methods using the `docx4j-6.1.1-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar` dependency? Can't those two be using different build versions of the `commons-codec` module?